# angular-ui select2 tagging - preselected tags id/text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, jquery-select2

This is my tags input

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="tags" class="input-large" ui-select2="{ tags: [{ id:5, text: 'tag1' }, { id: 8, text: 'tag2' }] }" />
```

now how do I make, say tag with id 5, preselected on load?

If I do $scope.tags = [5]; or even $scope.tags = 5 it makes a new tag with id 5 and text 5(though it removes from options).. I obviously want it to say "tag1", not 5, but still maintain the ID in the model..

Comment: How does this render? An hidden input with the class input-large and an object in the ui-select2 directive?

Comment: yeah, that's how select2 works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was actually with the version of select2 used. I was using 3.3.1, where it doesn't work, see http://plnkr.co/edit/Z53wvGKT1if1iZAVierY?p=preview

It works as expected when I use 3.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

What you demonstrated:

**HTML**

```
<p>
  <input type="text" ng-model="tags" 
         ui-select2="{tags: [{id:4, text:'red'},{id:2, text:'blue'},{id:8, text:'white'},{id:41, text:'green'},{id:13, text:'yellow'}]}" />
</p>
```

**Angular-UI**

```
angular.module('app').controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Will load shortly...";

  $scope.tags = [8, 2];

  $scope.message = 'Loaded';
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wUQq8P?p=preview

Why did it work then? I'm not sure. Perhaps there was a type or something did not load correctly. I've never used Angular or Select2, so it took me a few tries to get this to work.

Hmm. Well, copying your code into the plunk as-is, no other changes, I get:

http://embed.plnkr.co/wUQq8P

So I am guessing the problem I'm either not understanding or it was somewhere else in your code.

This is was the originally working example, using a method which can easily be paired with AJAX:

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h4>{{message}}</h4>
  <p>
    <input type="text" ui-select2="options" ng-model="tags" />
  </p>
</body>
```

**Angular-UI**

```
angular.module('app').controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Will load shortly...";

  $scope.options = {
    tags: [
      {id:4, text:'red'},
      {id:2, text:'blue'},
      {id:8, text:'white'},
      {id:41, text:'green'},
      {id:13, text:'yellow'}
    ]
  };

  $scope.tags = [8, 2];

  $scope.message = 'Loaded';
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wUQq8P?p=preview